# SequelizeJS allows UNIQUE field to be duplicated

Tags: node.js, database, sqlite, constraints, sequelize.js

in my web app (NodeJS + ExpressJS + SequelizeJS) i have defined the model User:

```
let User = connection.define('user', {
    username: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(40),
        unique: true,
        allowNull: false,
        validate: {
            notEmpty: true,
            min: 4,
        }
    },
    email: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        unique: true,
        allowNull: false,
        notEmpty: true,
        validate: {
            isEmail: true
        }
    },
    password: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        notEmpty: true,
        validate: {
            min: 8,

        }
    },
    name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(50),
        validate: {
            min: 2
        }
    },
    surname: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(50),
        validate: {
            min: 3
        }
    },
    bio: Sequelize.TEXT(140),
    lastLogin: Sequelize.DATE,
    dateJoined: Sequelize.DATE,
    active: {
        type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
        defaultValue: false
    }
});
```

I want both username and email to be unique so that no one can reuse an existing email or an existing username. 
So i tested it and i noticed that the query built is the following:

```
Executing (default): 
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user`(
`id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
`username` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
`email` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
`password` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
`nome` VARCHAR(50),
`cognome` VARCHAR(50),
`bio` TEXT,
`lastLogin` DATETIME,
`dateJoined` DATETIME,
`active` TINYINT(1) DEFAULT0,
`createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL,
`updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL);
```

And the query looks fine.
Then i decided to make the same insert query (whit the same username and email) every time my node server gets on, to test if the `NOT NULL` constraint is preserved.

```
User.create({
        username: 'MYUSERNAME',
        email: 'MYEMAIL@GMAIL.COM',
        password: 'MYPASSWORD'
    })
        .then(newUser => {
            console.log('Insertion OK, username:', newUser.username);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
```

The console output every time i restart my server:

```
Insertion OK, username: MYUSERNAME
```

And if i check the database records, in the user table i see multiple rows with the same data in the same fields.

```
-----------------------------------------------
| Username   | Email             | Password   |
-----------------------------------------------
| MYUSERNAME | MYEMAIL@GMAIL.COM | MYPASSWORD |
-----------------------------------------------
| MYUSERNAME | MYEMAIL@GMAIL.COM | MYPASSWORD |
-----------------------------------------------
| MYUSERNAME | MYEMAIL@GMAIL.COM | MYPASSWORD |
-----------------------------------------------
```

**Why doesn't it preserve the UNIQUE constraint?**

I'm using sqlite3 file for the database.

Comment: If you look at the definition of the table actually being used (open the database in the sqlite3 shell and run `.schema user`) does it have the unique constraints? You might be using an older version from before you added those (assuming you didn't have them from the start).

Comment: Yes i noticed using DBrowser for SQLite that username field was not set to unique. i manually set it to unique and now everything works but how can i solve this? Once the query is correctly built i'm not supposed to touch the database anymore and change things manually...

Comment: Sqlite has a way to store a version number in a database and many ORMs will check this against the expected version and call an upgrade function to give you a chance to create or modify tables as needed (or you can do it manually). No idea how that would work with your toolchain though.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I solved the same problem, **change** the email object of the user model **to**

```
email: {
  type: Sequelize.STRING,
  allowNull: false,
  notEmpty: true,
  validate: {
    isEmail: true
  },
  unique: 'email'
}
```

**Alternatively** If you want a custom validation error message

```
email: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        notEmpty: true,
        validate: {
            isEmail: true
        },
        unique: {
           args: 'email',
           msg: 'The email is already taken!'
        }
    }
```

**Remember** if you have a migration file, you should specify `unique: true` in the email object